# Замена " на ' и наоборот

Tags: python, python-3.7

Нужно реализовать функцию, которая получает строку и заменяет " на ' и наоборот
Написал код

```
def replace_quotes(input_string: str) -> str;
    for index, symbol in enumerate(input_string):
            if symbol == '\'':
                input_string = input_string[:index] + '\'' + input_string [index + 1:]
                continue
            if symbol == '\'' :
                input_string = input_string[:index] + '\'' + input_string [index + 1:]

return input_string
```

но мне возвращает ошибку

```
def replace_quotes(input_string: str) -> str;
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Роман, здесь а) говорят на русском, б) пытаются сделать хоть что-то самостоятельно.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: я пытался сделать через команду str.replace(' " ', ' ' '), но у меня выдает значение >>> str.replace ('"',''')

Comment: @RomanRutkovski Покажите, пожалуйста, Ваши попытки решения. Но не в комментариях, а в самом вопросе, предварительно переведя его на русский. Также стоит привести входные данные и саму ошибку. Сделать всё вышеперечисленное Вы можете, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Смотрите у вас опечатка `def replace_quotes(input_string: str) -> str;` в конце должно быть двоеточие. Кст, чтобы не делать экранирование кавычек, используйте другой вид строки, например: `'\''` -> `"'"` (т.е. одинарная кавычка внутри строки через двойные кавычки), и наоборот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/zIwXuT

```
def swap_quotes(s: str) -> str:
  dict = { '"':"'", "'":'"' }
  return ''.join(dict.get(c, c) for c in s)

print(swap_quotes(input()))
```